# Jquery appendTo doesn't work on ie8 compatibility view

Tags: jquery, append, ie8-compatibility-mode, appendto

i have a select when change append some divs with other elements, but in ie8 compatibility view doesn't work, no errors, no alerts, but dont know why
I got this code but doesn't work on ie8, compatibility view.
What can i do???

```
$('#frmAdd #emp_usa_presupuesto').change(function(){
var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        switch (selectedVal) {
        case '0':
            $('#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto').empty();
            $('#frmAdd #origenCC').empty();
            $('<label>Origen C.C.<span class="small">Origen Centro de Costo?</span></label>').appendTo('#frmAdd #origenCC');
            $('<select id="emp_origen_cc" name="emp_origen_cc"><option value="LOCAL">Local</option><option value="AS400">AS/400</option></select>').appendTo('#frmAdd #origenCC');
            $("#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto").append('<input type="hidden" value="" id="emp_origen_presupuesto" name="emp_origen_presupuesto"/>');
            break;
        case '1':
            $("#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto").empty();
            $("#frmAdd #origenCC").empty();
            $('<label>Origen<span class="small">Origen de Presupuesto?</span></label>').appendTo('#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto');
            $('<select id="emp_origen_presupuesto" name="emp_origen_presupuesto"><option value="LOCAL">Local</option><option value="AS400">AS/400</option></select>').appendTo('#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto');
            break;
        default:
            $("#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto").empty();
            $("#frmAdd #origenCC").empty();
            break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can just have `$('#origenPresupuesto')` instead of `$('#frmAdd #origenPresupuesto')`. - Just a suggestion

Comment: Why are you using "compatibility view"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Probably for testing